# javascript indexof array's element array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array and this array's elements is a array;

```
var array = [
    [0,1],
    [0,2],
    [0,3],
    [0,0]
];
```

But when i use array.indexOf([0,1]);
it return -1.

Comment: Here's a hint: `[] !== []`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: .........................................no

Comment: how can i use indexof(array)

Comment: `array.findIndex((el) => JSON.stringify(el) === JSON.stringify([0, 1]))`. If you want to use indexOf you need to have a reference to exact same element in array.

Comment: you can use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) `array.findIndex((v) => v[0] === 0 && v[1] === 1);`

Comment: thanks....................

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#findIndex` with your own implementation of equality comparison.

```js
var array = [
    [0,1],
    [0,2],
    [0,3],
    [0,0]
];
function equals(arr1, arr2){
  return arr1.length === arr2.length && arr1.every((x, i)=>x === arr2[i]);
}
let target = [0, 2];
let idx = array.findIndex(x => equals(x, target));
console.log(idx);
```